# ¿Cómo ocultar el cursor en java?

Tags: java, cursor, mouse

Estoy intetando hacer que cuándo el usuario entre a un JFrame en especifico el Cursor desaparezca y no reaparezca hasta que mueva el mouse y el MouseMotionListener lo detecte, si alguien tiene una idea de como hacerlo, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [ask], te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que has tratado o investigado, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el siguiente código en tu constructor:

```
    // Transparent 16 x 16 pixel cursor image.
    BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    // Create a new blank cursor.
    Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
    cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");
    // Set the blank cursor to the JFrame.
    getContentPane().setCursor(blankCursor);           

    //Retornando el cursor por default al mover el Mouse
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override    
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        getContentPane().setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }
    });        
    }
```

Comment: Dada la extensión de tus aportes no veo necesidad de publicar múltiples respuestaa, puedes editar y solo mejorar una de ambas

Comment: Te sugerimos publicar únicamente una respuesta, revisa el documento [answer] para crearla y esta sea de utilidad al OP, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al crear el JFrame agrega:

```
getContentPane().setCursor(null);
```

Luego agrega un evento para el mouse:

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        getGlassPane().setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }
});
```

Saludos.

Comment: Amigo agregué todo en el constructor y no me funcionó, ¿tienes idea a que se deba?

Comment: Te sugerimos publicar únicamente una respuesta, revisa el documento [answer] para crearla y esta sea de utilidad al OP, saludos.